# How to get value from DB in Struts 2 dropdown along with list

Tags: java, sorting, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am using Struts 2 framework for my application and my code is as follows,

```
/*Setting dynamic dropdown of service Type*/
ShowSearch drop=new ShowSearch();
service=drop.serviceType();
setService(service);
```

I am getting list of values from DB (Lets say values are "Apple","Cat","Jack","Zag") and it has shown in struts2 dropdown as mentioned in JSP .

```
<s:select id="serviceType" name="serviceType"
     label="What is the service offering" required="true"
     value="%{serviceType}" list="service" />
```

When I am trying to do below action, lets say `localhost:8080/as/prd?id=first`
Actual Value of the `"serviceType"` dropdown for 'first' is "Jack". But now, dropdown is showing in the order which is taken from DB (i.e based on list "Service").

My requirement is to show `"Jack"` then following `"Apple"`,`"Cat"`,`"Zag"`,`...`.  What should I do to show like that?

Answer (score 0):

Show like that is called sorting in the alphabetical order. To do that you could modify the list before the rendering phase. Assume your list collection element is a simple string, then

```
Collections.sort(myList);
```

will do what you want.

Another approach is to use `s:sort` tag and write a comparator which sort the list, then wrap it around the `s:select` tag

```xml
<s:sort comparator="myComparator" source="myList">
<s:select id="serviceType" name="serviceType"
             label="What is the service offering" required="true"
             value="%{serviceType}" list="myList" />
</s:sort>
```

Write a simple comparator

```
public Comparator getMyComparator() {
  return new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
      String s1 = (String) o1;
      String s2 = (String) o2;

      return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
  };
}
```

More detailed explanation how to sort collections and how to use `Comparable` and `Comparator` you could find [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/).

Comment: i dont need sorting here.. From Action class, i am getting one list and one string variable. I want to show in dropdown in jsp in such a way that, string comes first and then list..

Comment: It can display only the values in the list, I think you want to set a `headerValue` attribute.

Comment: I tried out setting header value. But unable to get the desired output.

Comment: What is the desired output, do you want to preset the value for the "Jack" to the list? Then you should return it from `getServiceType()`.

Answer (score 0):

set that string variable in your action class. Then that string variable will be displayed first in the dropdown.