# I want to display the key value bean based on sorting of value in Struts 2

Tags: java, sorting, jsp, struts2, comparator

I want to display the key value bean based on sorting of value in Struts 2.

```jsp
<s:select list="preferredBranchList"  listKey="displayKey"
          listValue="displayValue" name="preferredBranch" 
          cssClass="selectpicker show-tick" required="true"  />
```

It's sorting of the values based on `listKey`. Please, suggest me to sort the values based on `listValue`.

Comment: The `<s:select>` tag doesn't sort list it just iterates over it. So sort your `preferredBranchList` in action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and sort the values in Action class itself, so when select is rendered the list will appear sorted

Comment: How is this different from @AleksandrM's comment ?

Comment: Its not ... when i opened this page it didn't have any comments. So posted this as an answer. May be if SO can update the comments using Ajax the users will know what they are answering is not already answered.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to sort in action class and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `List` is an ordered collection. If it contains elements sorted by the key property then other the value property remains unsorted unless it's the same property. To make it sorted on another property you can sort the list with the comparator.

```
Collections.sort(myList, myComparator);
```

or you can use [`<s:sort>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/sort-tag.html) like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19856810/573032) example. And you only have to provide the comparator in the action class.