# Struts2 Iterator Sort List in reverse in order

Tags: java, struts2

Struts 2 Iterator Sort List in reverse in order

i need Sort List in reverse in order

ShowALL.jsp

```
    <div align="center">
        <table id="customers">
            <tr>
                <th>Batch Code</th>
                <th>Course</th>
                <th>LAb/ClassRoom</th>
                <th>Lecture Time</th>
                <th>Day's</th>
            </tr>

            <s:iterator value="list" status="rowstatus">
                <tr <s:if test="#rowstatus.odd">class="odd"</s:if>
                    <s:else>class="even"</s:else>>
                    <td><s:property value="BCode" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="Course" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="Lab" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="LectureT" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="Day" /></td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>

        </table>
    </div>
```

i need Sort List in reverse in order

Comment: Both answers sum up your options. Personally I think keeping as much logic out of the action as possible is a better approach, e.g., pass the sorted list to the JSP. If sorting itself is the issue then I'd search the web for "how to sort a list in Java" or something.

Comment: Not Use of Comparator it's simple to use of Collection in Action class   ```public String allList() {

  list = DaoBatch.alllist();
  ** List<Batch> shallowCopy = list.subList(0, list.size());
  Collections.reverse(shallowCopy); ***
  return SUCCESS;
 }```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31161422/573032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_iterator_tags.htm

You can use `<s:sort>` wrapped around your `<s:iterator>`:

```
<s:bean name="com.example.MyComparator" 
    var="myComparator" />

<s:sort comparator="myComparator" source="list">
    <s:iterator status="rowstatus">
        <tr <s:if test="#rowstatus.odd">class="odd"</s:if>
            <s:else>class="even"</s:else>>
            <td><s:property value="BCode" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="Course" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="Lab" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="LectureT" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="Day" /></td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</s:sort>
```

You'll just need to implement an appropriate Comparator to help sort your list.

Comment: what is logic we apply? in Comparator simple by id  reverse order list

Comment: I have no idea about the sorting logic.  All I know is that the struts tags let you apply a sort *if you have one*; figuring out *how* to sort your objects is a different question entirely.

Comment: @sammulla That's just plain Java; there are plenty of tutorials regarding Java sorts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better to sort list in controller and pass ready to use object to jsp

Comment: you have some example related to this question?

Comment: Action.execute() probably is the right place for it, see here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_actions.htm