# clear the old data in arraylist

Tags: java, struts2

I am working in struts2 based application in which we have different **area**, under which one or more **sites** covered, under sites, we have **divisions**,

the application basically allows user to upload documnent on the basis of monthly,quarterly,semiannual and annual basis.

currently all the area sorted by their name (i,e ascending) order. as shown in snapshot
[image]

As per snapshot there are some gray blocks has "NA" text on top of it.

What my requirement is all ***gray blocks should be below to red blocks in ascending order***

eg:

What I did, i calculated the count of **"NA"** and stored in variable just like `name`

currently counts are

1

0

3

0

In Code level I have utility which compute all the `sites` and one `universalcomparator` which accepts ***list of sites*** and ***method name***

The below code is responsible to sort my sites based on its name

```
 /*Hey sort method please sort sites based on its getName() method*/
    Collections.sort(sites, new UniversalComparator("getName", 1));
```

Compute All sites:

```
Utility.getInstance().computeSite(st, true, null, false, null, year);
```

Similarly, I have created an Integer variable in domain class `Site.java` and its corresponding getter setter.

```
private Integer siteNotAvailableCount;
```

somewhere inside `computeSite()` I have calculated the count

```
        site.setComparativeColorMonthly(comparativeColorSiteMonthly);
        site.setComparativeColorQuarterly(comparativeColorSiteQuarterly);
        site.setComparativeColorSemiAnnual(comparativeColorSiteSemiAnnual);
        site.setComparativeColorAnnual(comparativeColorSiteAnnual);
        
        int monthly = site.getComparativeColorMonthly().equalsIgnoreCase(AppConstants.WHITE)
                ? AppConstants._1
                : AppConstants._0;
        int semiAnnual = site.getComparativeColorSemiAnnual().equalsIgnoreCase(AppConstants.WHITE)
                ? AppConstants._1
                : AppConstants._0;
        int quaterly = site.getComparativeColorQuarterly().equalsIgnoreCase(AppConstants.WHITE)
                ? AppConstants._1
                : AppConstants._0;
        int annual = site.getComparativeColorAnnual().equalsIgnoreCase(AppConstants.WHITE)
                ? AppConstants._1
                : AppConstants._0;
        Integer countSiteNA = monthly + semiAnnual + quaterly + annual;
        site.setSiteNotAvailableCount(countSiteNA)
```

**Final STEP:**
just like below snippet

```
Collections.sort(sites, new UniversalComparator("getName", 1))
```

I have tried this

```
  /*Hey sort method please sort sites based on its NA count */
    Collections.sort(sites, new UniversalComparator("getSiteNotAvailableCount", 1))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1
0
0
3
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.lear.common.utility.UniversalComparator.compare(UniversalComparator.java:104)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:324)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:189)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
    at com.lear.scorecard.ScorecardManager.getComparativeSiteAnalysis(ScorecardManager.java:718)
    at com.lear.web.DashBoardAction.comparativeSiteAnalysis(DashBoardAction.java:294)
```

It complaints on line 104 of universal comparator here it is i,e `Comparable c2 = (Comparable) comp2;`

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        Object comp1 = null;
        Object comp2 = null;

        try {
            Method o1_Method = (o1.getClass()).getMethod(methodName, null);
            Method o2_Method = (o2.getClass()).getMethod(methodName, null);
            comp1 = o1_Method.invoke(o1, null);
            comp2 = o2_Method.invoke(o2, null);

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Method does not exist" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Illegal access" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("InvocationTargetException"
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
        Comparable c1 = (Comparable) comp1;
        Comparable c2 = (Comparable) comp2;// HERE 
        return c1.compareTo(c2) * descAscIndicator;
    }
```

**ROOT CAUSE:**

```
public String getComparartiveAnalysis(Integer divId)
{
if(divId!=null){

  //plenty of code
  //somewhere in code 

sites = dao.getAllSiteDataByDivision(12, year, divId); // VERY FIRST TIME INITALIZATION FOUND **TEST 1** and **TEST 10** sites, ALL COLOR CODES ARE NULL

                if (sites == null || sites.isEmpty()) {
                    logger.debug("No Transaction data found.");
                    sites = dao.getAllSitesWithDivisions(divId, true); // /

                } else {
                    logger.debug("Checking new Site added with no tranaction data");
                    List<Site> siteAllList = dao.getAllSitesWithDivisions(divId, true); // /
                    for (Iterator iterator = siteAllList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                        Site st = (Site) iterator.next();
                        Utility.getInstance().computeSite(st, true, null, false, null, year);// THIS LINE SET COLOR CODES like WHITE, RED and GREEN
                        System.out.println("naSiteCount------>" + st.getSiteNotAvailableCount() == null ? 0
                                : st.getSiteNotAvailableCount());
                        if (!sites.contains(st)) {
                            sites.add(st);
                        }
                    }

                }

}
}
```

**DEBUG REPORT**

On debugging, I found the color codes for **Test 1** [null,null,null,null] and **Test 10 [null,null,null,null]** is **NULL**, whereas color code for **TEST1005 is [RED,GRAY,GRAY,GRAY]** and **Test23122014 [RED,RED,RED,RED]**.

That is the reason when it is going to compare it with NULL, it throws NPE,

**TRIED SOLUTION:**

I have tried **sites.clear()** method but that ddin't work, I need to clear data that is coming from `dao.getAllSiteDataByDivision(12, year, divId)` because its not updated my list after calling `computeSite()` i need a way to implement the same efficiently or if you people have some other suggestion for me, I welcoming that too

```
Utility.getInstance().computeSite(st, true, null, false, null, year);
```

The above line computes the color codes for all the sites, but `sites` previously initialized by

```
sites = dao.getAllSiteDataByDivision(12, year, divId);
```

and it fetches `Test1` and `Test10`

I want to clear those previous data and got latest one from `computeSite()`
function.

Please help me to achieve the same.

Comment: `AppConstants._1`? The whole point of naming things is to provide *information*, e.g., what does `1` *mean* in a given context. Without that you might just as well use `1`. I mean, okay, this should be an enum anyway, but still. In any case: I'd consider... debugging the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31161422/573032

Comment: @Dave, it is simple mathematics computation, it count number of "N/A" blocks, if found then 1, if not then 0, AppConstants._1 = 1 and AppConstants._0

Comment: By the way I have found the root cause of NPE, please see my edits

Comment: @user9634982 Totally irrelevant to the point.

Comment: I have changed my title now, checl